# RabbitMQ + PHP deployment strategy

Tags: php, deployment, rabbitmq

I have a PHP project (Symfony2) that uses RabbitMQ. I use its as simple message queue to delay some jobs (sending mails, important data from APIs). The consumers run on the webserver and their code is part of the webserver repo - they are deployed in the same with with the web.

The questions are: 
How do I start the consumers as daemons and make sure they always run?
When deploying the app, how do I shut down consumers "gracefully" so that they stop consuming but finish processing the message they started?

If it's any important, for deployment I use Capifony.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It maybe worth looking at something [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which is written in python. I've used it before for running workers for Gearmand which is a job queue that fullfils a similar role to the way your using RabbitMQ.

Comment: That looks very promising, although it doesn't solve one importnt issue - shutting down consumers gracefully (ie. not killing them). I will try to get around that.

Comment: Ah-ah, I think I solved that by making my PHP workers listen for certain system signals and then once received, would terminate after they finished their current job. Supervisord can be configured to send different signals to process, not just the Kill -9 equivalent.